# Display Gallery images in list

Tags: magento-1.9, php

Like we view Gallery images in **View** template by default,

I tried to copy chidHtml code of **View/Media** for Gallery images into my **List** page.

But it is not working.

The code I pasted for Gallery images in my **List** template is,

```
<?php if (count($this->getGalleryImages()) > 0): ?>
<div class="more-views">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('More Views') ?></h2>
    <ul class="product-image-thumbs">
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
        <?php if ($this->isGalleryImageVisible($_image)): ?>
        <li>
            <a class="thumb-link" href="#" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>" data-image-index="<?php echo $i; ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(75); ?>"
                     width="75" height="75" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You can not use direct above code in list file.

Comment: view/media.phtml file is associated with `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Media` Block where `getGalleryImages()` function resides. Where as list.phtml is associated with `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` Block.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to call `media` block in list page, or any other page then you can call `media` block via below code

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view')->setProduct($_product)->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/media.phtml');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code :

```
<?php $probj=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId()); ?>
<?php $gallery_image = $probj->getMediaGalleryImages(); ?>

<?php foreach ($gallery_image as $image_gallery) :?>

<img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image', $image_gallery->getFile())->resize(100, 100); ?>" alt="<?php echo $_product->getName()?>" />

<?php endforeach; ?>
```